# Can Numba be used with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, numba

Can Numba be used to compile Python code which interfaces with Tensorflow? I.e. computations outside of the Tensorflow universe would run with Numba for speed. I have not found any resources on how to do this.

Comment: see this issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47

Comment: You could fetch numpy arrays from TensorFlow using `session.run`, run numba on them, and then feed result back into TF using `feed_dict`

Answer (score 8):

You can use [tf.numpy_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function), or [tf.py_func](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) to wrap a python function and use it as a TensorFlow op. Here is an example which I used:

```
@jit
def dice_coeff_nb(y_true, y_pred):
    "Calculates dice coefficient"
    smooth = np.float32(1)
    y_true_f = np.reshape(y_true, [-1])
    y_pred_f = np.reshape(y_pred, [-1])
    intersection = np.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    score = (2. * intersection + smooth) / (np.sum(y_true_f) +
                                            np.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
    return score

@jit
def dice_loss_nb(y_true, y_pred):
    "Calculates dice loss"
    loss = 1 - dice_coeff_nb(y_true, y_pred)
    return loss

def bce_dice_loss_nb(y_true, y_pred):
    "Adds dice_loss to categorical_crossentropy"
    loss =  tf.numpy_function(dice_loss_nb, [y_true, y_pred], tf.float64) + \
            tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    return loss
```

Then I used this loss function in training a tf.keras model:

```
...
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=bce_dice_loss_nb)
```

Answer (score 5):

I know that this does not directly answer you question, but it might be a good alternative. Numba is using just-in-time (JIT) Compilation. So, you can follow the instruction at the official TensorFlow documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/jit) on how to use JIT (but not in Numba ecosystem) in TensorFlow.