# Can Numba be used to subclass a Keras Layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, numba

I am aware that numba [can be used with Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132633/can-numba-be-used-with-tensorflow). However in my case I'm trying to subclass a `Layer`, so that solution doesn't work for me.

```py
import numpy as np
import numba
import tensorflow as tf

@numba.jit(nopython = True)
def func(param, input):
    return param*input**2

@numba.jit(nopython = True)
def gradfunc(param, input):
    return input**2

@tf.custom_gradient
def func_tf(param, input):
    p = param.numpy()
    i = input.numpy()
    def grad(dy):
        return tf.numpy_function(gradfunc, (p, i), tf.float32), 2*p*i 
    return tf.numpy_function(func, (p, i), tf.float32), grad

class myLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.param = self.add_weight("param")
        
    def call(self, input):
        return func_tf(self.param, input)
    
class myModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_layers):
        super().__init__(name='')
        self._layers = [myLayer() for _ in range(num_layers)]
        
    def call(self, input_tensor):
        for layer in self._layers:
            input_tensor = layer(input_tensor)
        return input_tensor
    
model = myModel(3)
print(model(1.5)) # <-- this works
```

This part is okay, because in eager mode `.numpy()` is allowed. However, training fails:

```py
def loss(target, output):
    return tf.abs(tf.reduce_sum(target - output))**2

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=loss,
    metrics=[loss])

model.fit([0.1], [0.4], batch_size=None)
```

because `model.fit` uses `@tf.function` under the hood, so the calls to `.numpy()` in `func` and `gradfunc` are not allowed (see issue [#40508](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40508) on GitHub).

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Your code should work if instead of using `.numpy()` in `tf_func` you pass `params` and `input` directly to [`tf.numpy_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function):

```py
@tf.custom_gradient
def func_tf(param, input):
    param = tf.convert_to_tensor(param)
    input = tf.convert_to_tensor(input)
    def grad(dy):
        return tf.numpy_function(gradfunc, (param, input), tf.float32), 2 * param * input
    return tf.numpy_function(func, (param, input), tf.float32), grad
```

The [`tf.convert_to_tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor) are there because [`tf.numpy_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function) expects strictly  [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor) objects, so if you directly use `params`, which will be a variable passed from `myLayer`, it will not work as expected.

For some reason, the code still gives an error about shapes after this. I got it to run properly changing the shape of the `param` weight to `[1, 1]`:

```py
self.param = self.add_weight("param", shape=[1, 1])
```

---

You can pass `run_eagerly=True` to [`compile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile) to force Keras to use eager mode (i.e. without [`tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function)) for training:

```py
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=loss,
    metrics=[loss],
    run_eagerly=True)
```

Comment: That's true (thanks for the suggestion), but it slows down the training by a least 10x 

Comment: @Ziofil Yes, doesn't really surprise me... Unfortunately there is not much way around it, if you want to incorporate NumPy/Numba code into the training you will need to run eagerly... The alternative is to port the Numba code to TensorFlow, which I don't know if would be feasible in your case (and it could be that the TensorFlow implementation is slower than the Numba one).

Comment: I see. But in principle it should be implementable at the level of the internals of Keras and TF: if one defines an op as a black box with its own custom gradient, it should be "pluggable" in the computational graph as is...

Comment: @Ziofil Wait, I just realised, why are you using `.numpy()` at all in your code? You don't need `p` and `i` in `func_tf`, you should be using `param` and `input`. That would allow the code to be wrapped into a `tf.function`.

Comment: Well, `input` is passed as a value, but `param` is passed as a Tensor, so if I don't use `.numpy()`, it doesn't work... (unless I'm missing something)

Comment: @Ziofil Updated with a working solution for your code, hope that's clear.